# How do I interpret the scale factor as a quantity that needs to be divided?

Tags: arithmetic, ratio

The quantities which are often required to be multiplied to get a fractions of the original value lie between 0 to 1.The operation seems very intuitive to me. However while I need to divide a quantity by such a value I end up having problems with the intuition. Dividing by a value intentionally to get a larger value is something that seems very very non intuitive. Please give me a detailed insight into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dividing and multiplication are inverses. If multiplying by a number between $0$ and $1$ makes the quantity smaller then dividing by it should make it bigger since the division "undoes" the multiplication. For example, multiplying by $0.5$ halves the original quantity. Dividing by $0.5$ doubles the quantity since halving and doubling are inverses of each other (they undo each other).